# Positions of elements HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having issue with positioning these boxes. Is there someone that know how to make it exactly same as it's on picture?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aW9B.png

Deleted some parts from CSS because they aren't important for this.

CSS & HTML

```css
.aktualita-perex{
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 color: #4c4c4c;
}

.aktualita-img{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}

.aktualita-thumbmail{
 width: 100%;
 height: 216px;
 object-fit: cover;
}   
 
.aktualita-header{
 color: #282828;
 font-size: 27px;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.aktualita-body{
 padding: 15px;
 float: left;
}
  
.aktualita-container{
 width: 383px;
 border: 1px rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.19) solid;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<article class="aktualita-container">
<div class="aktualita-thumbmail">
<div class="aktualita-img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/x3lpHuG.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
<div class="aktualita-datum">25. Ledna 2017</div>
</div>
<div class="aktualita-body">
<div class="aktualita-header">Aqualand Moravia</div>
<div class="aktualita-perex">SOME TEXT</div>
<div class="aktualita-tlacitko">Číst více</div>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to provide, showing what you've tried?

Comment: hi, first you need to add your code here to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your floats are off because of your container heights.  To make it seamless you need to have your heights all be the same id suggest increasing the height or adding a height (if you don't currently have one on your container) until you get the seamless look you are looking for.

Comment: I'd like to have it dynamic.

Comment: That is what is causing your issue.  The dynamic heights are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `float: left`  and make them `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular situation you can add `clear: left` to the CSS of the container/article tag which you want to move to the left.

But in general, as @oompahlumpa wrote, you should set all your containers to the same height.